# Парсинг значения, из ответа на GET запрос

Tags: javascript, get

Всем доброго. Подскажите, как спарсить значение из строки `is_error_send`(0 или 1):

```js
{"count":1,
  "code":0,
  "data":[
             {
               "id":01010101,
               "phone":"79111111111",
               "date":"2000-01-1 01:01:11",
                "msg":"test",
                "id_device":1111,
                "send_to_phone":"2000-01-1 01:01:1",
                "is_send_to_phone":1,
                "is_send":1,
                "send":"2000-01-1 01:01:1",
                "is_delivered":1,
                "delivered":"2000-01-1 01:01:11",
                "is_cancel":0,
                "cancel":null,
                "is_error":0,
                "is_error_send":0,
                "error_date":null,
                "is_out":0,
                "type":2,
                "my_id":{}
               }
             ]
}
```

с помощью `responseText.replace(/[^\\d]/g, '').slice(0, 1)`, в этом случае данное выражение берет первую цифру, а у меня задачка по сложнее...

Вот пример реализации, увы не работает:

```js
var xap = new XMLHttpRequest();
xap.open('GET', 'https://site.ru/api/out.php?token=1111&device=0101&start_id=0101&end_id=0101', true);
xap.send();
xap.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xap.readyState == 4){
        if(xap.status == 200){
                console.log('result', responseText.data[0].is_error_send);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: это обычный объект. никакие регулярные выражения тут не нужны. нужно работать как с обычным объектом и массивом (во всяком случае возвращаемое значение должно быть в итоге json)

Comment: `responseText.data[0].is_error_send` - как то так

Comment: Увы, это не работает

Comment: @SwaD неее. там скорее всего надо `JSON.parse` вначале сделать, потому что ТС это не обозначил в запросе к серверу

Comment: Виноват, сейчас поправлю вопрос, добавлю код которым делаю запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вам рекомендовал использовать более современные способы отправки данных, например [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

```
fetch('https://site.ru/api/out.php?token=1111&device=0101&start_id=0101&end_id=0101', {
  method: 'GET'
})
.then(res => res.json()) // Преобразуем ответ в json
.then(responseText => console.log(responseText.data[0].is_error_send))
```

fetch сделает GET запрос по указанному адресу, когда вернется ответ, его обработает первый .then() и преобразует ответ(это текст) в формат объекта(JSON).

Далее вызов будет передан во второй .then() где уже можете делать с полученным объектом необходимые действия.

В примере выше, вывод значения в консоль

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, поправил. Но в другую сторону, что бы было похоже на переменные в вопросе :)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1):

Вначале надо сделать перевод текста в обычный json:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

Теперь можно обращатсья с переменной `obj`, как с обычным объектом: свойствам обращатсья через точку, а к элементам массива - по индексу

---

Кстати, должно быть не `responseText`, а `xap.responseText`

---

Если указать тип ответа `xap.responseType = "json";`, то никакие `JSON.parse` уже не нужны будут

Comment: xap.responseText да, вы правы, так тоже пробовал, не выходит

Comment: И еще можно рекомендовать на `fetch` переехать, там и `respnose.json()` красиво бы встраивался ) А то все эти var похожи на методички 10 летней давности

Comment: @Влад ещё раз посмотрите ответ. надо либо использовать парсинг в json, либо указать тип возвращаемого значения json, чтобы работать как с объектом в итоге......ну и фраза *"не выходит"* --- не говорит никому ни о чём

Comment: @Влад в вашем коде можно попробовать не `xap.responseText` а `this.responseText`